# What is the best way to model guitar body waist chamfer?

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to model a guitar as a practice, but I can't figure out how to best get this guitar body waist chamfer. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Please make an effort to describe what you want as part of the title. Read: [What is the problem with posting an image (or link) and asking ""How do I do this?"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "*this*", "*help with*", "*issue*" or "*question about*", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 3):

Draw the shape:

[image]

Extrude:

[image]

Push these vertices:

[image]

Rearrange the topology:

[image]